# Project Euler #19. Trouble Understanding

Tags: algorithm

So I started problem 19 thinking it would be really easy, however I don't think I understand what the question is asking.

The Question:

You are given the following information, but you may prefer to do some research for yourself.

1 Jan 1900 was a Monday.
Thirty days has September,
April, June and November.
All the rest have thirty-one,
Saving February alone,
Which has twenty-eight, rain or shine.
And on leap years, twenty-nine.
A leap year occurs on any year evenly divisible by 4, but not on a century unless it is divisible by 400.

How many Sundays fell on the first of the month during the twentieth century (1 Jan 1901 to 31 Dec 2000)?

As I understand this, I find it to be asking how many Sundays were there in January of each year from 1901-2000. There are around 3 Sundays in each month (that's lowballing it) and over 100 years, that's 100 Januaries, so 100*3 is around 300.Apparently it's around 100 which is obviously wrong by my question so if someone could explain to me what this question is actually asking, that would be great.

Comment: You can't approximate it like that, the question is spelled out quite clearly (only the last part matters), what part are you unsure about?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about contest description comprehension, not programming.

Comment: Agreed; I'm pretty sure English comprehension is not programming :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not asking you how many Sundays were in January.  It's how many times a month *started* with a Sunday.

If you [check a calendar for the year 1900](http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=1900), you can see that April 1 is a Sunday and July 1 is a Sunday.  So for that year, there were only two months that meet the criteria.  [The year 1901](http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=1901) has two days that meet the criteria again (September 1 and December 1), and [the year 1902](http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=1902) has only one day (June 1).